# What can prevent me from making remote access to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, networking, centos7, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to make remote access to postgresql that I installed on a VM with centos 7, but I get the following error:

> " Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running
>   on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port
>   5432? "

know that I have already changed the files pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf but this did not work

Comment: Did you answer the question asked by the message?

Comment: There are many options. A web search will help (you are not the first person with that problem). Try to narrow down if it is a network or database configuration problem (hint: PostgreSQL log file).

Comment: lurker, i edited my post to take this doubt. Laurenz, there are many options because I do not know exactly where the problem is. I've done a lot of research on the web but the vast majority is just about the pg_hba.config and postgresql.config files.